# PhpSpreadsheet vs PhpExcel active cell start numbers. What are the correct values?

Tags: phpexcel, phpoffice, phpspreadsheet

We were using Excel but now started using Spreadsheet as it is the future.
Recently in our app, i have to make a change,

This is our excel file logic.

FROM

```
var $excel_start_row_index=1;
var $excel_start_column_index=0;
```

TO

```
var $excel_start_row_index=1;
var $excel_start_column_index=1;
```

Because we were not showing one column. Maybe I think it happened with our current composer update. So I see some other changes in how to style and applyFromArray has new style array for setting the background color. So is this change in the library to get start cell.

I see

```
namespace PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet;
/**
 * Active cell. (Only one!).
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $activeCell = 'A1';


But where can I find the numerical representation of it? Like $activeColumn = 0 , $activeRow = 1. something like it.
```

What is the numerical equivalent of "A" here is it 0 or 1.

Here [Github Issue See the second comment by Mark Baker](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/390) he says it starts with 0 in PhpExcel. Is it same in PhpSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much discussion and debate, it was decided to start column indexing from 1 to try and be more consistent https://gitter.im/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet?at=59fa9f27976e63937e17fd27